# PowerShell Scipt for adding new Credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, credentials

I'm trying to make script to automaticly assign credidentials based on the group that was chose. I'm getting a lot of syntax errors. Can you help?

```
 Function Add-OSCCredential
{
    $target = Read-Host "Group number"
    If($target)
    {
        If($target -eq 1)
        {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group1 /user:Group1 /pass:Pass1}
        [ElseIf($target -eq 2)
        {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group2 /user:Group2 /pass:Pass2}]
        {
        [ElseIf($target -eq 3)
        {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group3 /user:Group3 /pass:Pass3}]
        {
        If($result -match "The command line parameters are incorrect")
            {Write-Error "Failed to add Windows Credential to Windows vault."}
        ElseIf($result -match "CMDKEY: Credential added successfully")
            {Write-Host "Credential added successfully."}
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Error "Internet(network address) or username can not be empty,please try again."
        Add-OSCCredential
    }

}

Add-OSCCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a proper editor such as vscode which will give you lots of hints concerning bad syntax.

In your case there are a lot of `[]` and `{}` parenthesis that do not make sense.

Only considering the syntax of that function, the following should 'work':

```
Function Add-OSCCredential {
  $target = Read-Host "Group number"
  If ($target) {
    If ($target -eq 1) {
      [string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group1 /user:Group1 /pass:Pass1
    }
    ElseIf ($target -eq 2) {
      [string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group2 /user:Group2 /pass:Pass2
    }
    ElseIf ($target -eq 3) {
      [string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group3 /user:Group3 /pass:Pass3
    }

    If ($result -match "The command line parameters are incorrect") {
      Write-Error "Failed to add Windows Credential to Windows vault."
    }
    ElseIf ($result -match "CMDKEY: Credential added successfully") {
      Write-Host "Credential added successfully."
    }
  }
  Else {
    Write-Error "Internet(network address) or username can not be empty,please try again."
    Add-OSCCredential
  }

}
```

---

edit:

you'd most likely want to look into a ready-to-use PowerShell Module such as [CredentialManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager), this way you wouldn't have to fiddle with cmdkey.exe yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value for `Read-Host` is always a string, but you treat it like an integer in your tests.
For better readability, I suggest using a `switch` rather that yet another set of `if..elseif..else` statements.

Something like this:

```
function Add-OSCCredential {
    $target = Read-Host "Enter Group number (1-3)"
    if ($target -match '1|2|3') {
        switch ([int]$target) {
            1 {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group1 /user:Group1 /pass:Pass1}
            2 {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group2 /user:Group2 /pass:Pass2}
            3 {[string]$result = cmdkey /add:Group3 /user:Group3 /pass:Pass3}
        }
        if($result -match "The command line parameters are incorrect") {
            Write-Error "Failed to add Windows Credential to Windows vault."
        }
        elseif ($result -match "Credential added successfully") {
            Write-Host "Credential added successfully."
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning $result
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Group number must be either 1, 2 or 3. Please try again."
        Add-OSCCredential
    }
}

Add-OSCCredential
```